# php foreach not working properly on json object

Tags: php, json, parsing, loops, stdclass

This thread debates whether to do it this way or that way. The truth is either one is insufficient without the other. THE SOLUTION (along with a clearer description of the problem) CAN BE FOUND HERE:

[how to iterate over JSON property not knowing if it's array or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313890/how-to-iterate-over-json-property-not-knowing-if-its-array-or-not)

---

I have the following JSON parsed as an object (stdClass):

```
{
   "getdeparturesresult":{
      "departuresegment":{
         "departure":{
            "location":{
               "@id":"7461018",
               "@x":"12.523958",
               "@y":"57.938402",
               "name":"Noltorps centrum"
            },
            "datetime":"2014-12-04 23:05"
         },
         "direction":"Alingsås station",
         "segmentid":{
            "mot":{
               "@displaytype":"B",
               "@type":"BLT",
               "#text":"Buss"
            },
            "carrier":{
               "name":"Västtrafik",
               "url":"http://www.vasttrafik.se/",
               "id":"279",
               "number":"1"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the same in XML, more readable, haven't been able to pretty-print the JSON this good in my var_dump...

```
<getdeparturesresult>
    <departuresegment>
        <departure>
            <location id="7461018" x="12.523958" y="57.938402">
                <name>Noltorps centrum</name>
            </location>
            <datetime>2014-12-04 23:05</datetime>
        </departure>
        <direction>Alingsås station</direction>
        <segmentid>
            <mot displaytype="B" type="BLT">Buss</mot>
            <carrier>
                    <name>Västtrafik</name>
                    <url>http://www.vasttrafik.se/</url>
                <id>279</id>
                <number>1</number>
            </carrier>
        </segmentid>
    </departuresegment>
</getdeparturesresult>
```

I iterate over it by this code...

```
        $r=array();
        $i=0;

        foreach ($apiData->getdeparturesresult->departuresegment as $m) {

            $r[$i]["depTime"] = $m->departure->datetime; //tid för avgången
            $segmentid = get_object_vars($m->segmentid->mot);
            $r[$i]["typText"] = $segmentid['#text'];
            //$r[$i]["typ"] = $segmentid['@displaytype'];
            $r[$i]["nr"] = $m->segmentid->carrier->number;
            $r[$i]["destination"] = $m->direction; //slutstation (som står på bussen, tåget etc.)
            $r[$i]["operator"] = $m->segmentid->carrier->name;

            $i++;

        }
```

...and it works well until I get a response like this one with only one DEPARTURE element in it, in which case I am thrown this error:

```
(http500) Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$departure
```

So it seems to me that the loop attempts a second run, in the which it fails on the first line

```
$r[$i]["depTime"] = $m->departure->datetime; //tid för avgången
```

since $m->departure doesn't exist. But why then would $m even exist itself?

----- UPDATE -------

This is what the JSON looks like when there are several items in DEPARTURESEGMENT:

```
{
  "getdeparturesresult":{
     "departuresegment":[{
        "departure":{
           "location":{
              "@id":"7461018",
              "@x":"12.523958",
              "@y":"57.938402",
              "name":"Noltorps centrum"
           },
           "datetime":"2014-12-04 23:05"
        },
        "direction":"Alingsås station",
        "segmentid":{
           "mot":{
              "@displaytype":"B",
              "@type":"BLT",
              "#text":"Buss"
           },
           "carrier":{
              "name":"Västtrafik",
              "url":"http://www.vasttrafik.se/",
              "id":"279",
              "number":"1"
           }
        }
     },
     {
        "departure":{
           "location":{
              "@id":"7461018",
              "@x":"12.523958",
              "@y":"57.938402",
              "name":"Noltorps centrum"
           },
           "datetime":"2014-12-04 23:05"
        },
        "direction":"Alingsås station",
        "segmentid":{
           "mot":{
              "@displaytype":"B",
              "@type":"BLT",
              "#text":"Buss"
           },
           "carrier":{
              "name":"Västtrafik",
              "url":"http://www.vasttrafik.se/",
              "id":"279",
              "number":"1"
           }
        }
     }
     ]
  }
}
```

In this case, the loop I have works fine. When there is only one item though, I need a loop like @chiliNUTS descriped, going one level shallower in the foreach condition.

Is there a way to write a loop that will iterate over an array of objects in DEPARTURESEGMENT if it is an array, and only pull the values from that first object if not? Would I have to put a separate if-clause before the loop to test if looping is actually necessary (and thus doubling up on the logics that picks up the values I want, both in the loop and outside of it)?

Comment: `But why then would $m even exist itself?` it will go through the properties of the object. Look at http://pastebin.com/pUv2eAgK and you will understand.

Comment: Yes but it should go over the DEPARTURESEGMENTs right? And there is only one of those.

Comment: The loop will go through `departure`, `direction` and so on. So, `$m` will not have `departure` in it, because at the first loop it will be already `departure`

Comment: if departuresegment is always settet `$m` by default is an empty stdclass, if you put items on it it will become an array **IF there are more than one element**, if not, its an stdclass - since your error shows that the departure element doesnt exist, what is holding the whole `$apiData->getdeparturesresult->departuresegment` element? - anyways you can check befor the foreach loop if your element is an stdclass, otherwise set `$apiData->getdeparturesresult->departuresegment = array($apiData->getdeparturesresult->departuresegment)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$m` *is* `departure`. you're looping thru each element of `departuresegment`. so first `$m` is `departure` then its `direction`, then its `segmentid`. you probably just want

`foreach ($apiData->getdeparturesresult->departuresegment as $m)`

**TEST**

```
$json = '{"getdeparturesresult":{"departuresegment":{"departure":{"location":{"@id":"7461018","@x":"12.523958","@y":"57.938402","name":"Noltorps centrum"},"datetime":"2014-12-04 23:05"},"direction":"Alingsås station","segmentid":{"mot":{"@displaytype":"B","@type":"BLT","#text":"Buss"},"carrier":{"name":"Västtrafik","url":"http:\/\/www.vasttrafik.se\/","id":"279","number":"1"}}}}}';
$apiData = json_decode($json);
foreach ($apiData->getdeparturesresult->departuresegment as $key => $m) {
    echo "key:" . $key . "\r\n";
    echo '$m:' . print_r($m, true);
    echo "\r\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
key:departure
$m:stdClass Object
(
    [location] => stdClass Object
        (
            [@id] => 7461018
            [@x] => 12.523958
            [@y] => 57.938402
            [name] => Noltorps centrum
        )

    [datetime] => 2014-12-04 23:05
)

key:direction
$m:Alingsås station
key:segmentid
$m:stdClass Object
(
    [mot] => stdClass Object
        (
            [@displaytype] => B
            [@type] => BLT
            [#text] => Buss
        )

    [carrier] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Västtrafik
            [url] => http://www.vasttrafik.se/
            [id] => 279
            [number] => 1
        )

)
```

Only the first one has a datetime...

Comment: No that's not the problem, it works fine with more than one elements in the answer. I don't look for depTime in all sub-elements, I only pick depTime from the departure element (see the code in the loop). I'm not iterating over the DEPARTURE element/property, I am iterating over it's parent DEPARTURESEGMENT

Comment: @MattiasSvensson: do you mean that when you have only one departure, your json looks like this: {"getdeparturesresult":{"departure": ...}} ?

Comment: see the edit it looks your loop is not doing what you expect

Comment: No, if $m would have been DEPARTURE then it would fail EVERY TIME on the first line inside the loop, since $m being DEPARTURE would never have a child property called DEPARTURE. Like I said, it works fine as long as there are more than 1 departuresegment element.

Comment: @anhlc no, the structure is still the same, the problem arises when there is only one DEPARTURESEGMENT (the parent of departure, direction and segmentid).

Comment: @chiliNUT you are right, of course, but I hadn't presented/identified the entire problem. See my edits and the other thread I started to clearify it all.